# How to plot an exponential distribution

Tags: r, plot, exponential

I want to plot an exponential distribution, something like this for example: [image]

But I only know how to simulate a data frame that follow a exponential distribution and plot it.

```
data =  data.frame(x=rexp(n = 100000, rate = .65))
m <- ggplot(data, aes(x=data$x))
m + geom_density()
```

From which I get: 
[image]

How can I plot the true exponential distribution instead of a sampled version of the distribution?

Comment: `curve(0.65*exp(-0.65*x), from=0, to=10)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The exponential distribution can be obtained with the `dexp` function, so you can plot it by sampling `x` values and processing them with that function:

```
x <- seq(0, 20, length.out=1000)
dat <- data.frame(x=x, px=dexp(x, rate=0.65))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=px)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This might be one of those examples where base R is easier than ggplot:

```
curve(dexp, xlim=c(0,10))
```

[image]

And a ggplot solution that takes advantage of `stat_function(...)`, which was intended for this.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x=seq(0,10,by=0.1))
ggplot(df) + stat_function(aes(x),fun=dexp)
```

[image]

Comment: Does this solution work even if you need to assign a parameter like `rate` as used on the accepted answer?

Comment: @Blaszard you could do `curve(dexp(x, rate=1/2), xlim=c(1,10))` or `stat_function(aes(x), fun=function(x) dexp(x, rate=1/2))`

Answer (score 6):

I believe you are might want to do something like

```
h<-ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0,7)),aes(x=x))
h<-h+stat_function(fun=dexp,geom = "line",size=2,col="blue",args = (mean=1.5))
h<-h+stat_function(fun=dexp,geom = "line",size=2,col="green",args = (mean=1))
h<-h+stat_function(fun=dexp,geom = "line",size=2,col="red",args = (mean=0.5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
setwd("J:/R projects/phoenixhsl/R scripts")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0,7)),aes(x=x))+stat_function(fun=dexp,geom =    "line",size=2,col="orange",args = (mean=0.5))
 ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0,7)),aes(x=x))+stat_function(fun=dexp,geom =     "line",size=2,col="purple",args = (mean=1))
  ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0,7)),aes(x=x))+stat_function(fun=dexp,geom =     "line",size=2,col="blue",args = (mean=1.5))
```